# How to check if Laravel command is still running?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I've searched around and I cannot find the answer.

So, is there a way to check if the custom Laravel command that we have started still running, or it has finished it's job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always log information into the log files when running certain commands that you wish to confirm ran or not.

You can place the log code directly inside your command's handle method.

```
    public function handle()
    {
        // Handle some command logic...

        Log::info('This is some useful information about the command that just ran its course.');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So, you suggest to write to the log and later read the log to see if task is finished?

Comment: I guess that is the simplest way to go about it. As far as I am aware Laravel 5 creates new log files for each day and keeps track of the last 5 days of logs so you can easily search to see if the command ran on a particular day and how many times too. You could follow a specific way to log like `Log::info('MyCommand: And then some information');`. This way you can just hit Ctrl+F and search for 'MyCommand'.  I hope this helps.